# How can I control the color of my Vim terminal?

Tags: terminal, vim9

I'm using the nord theme on gVim 9.0.

My Vim terminal appear with Black color:

Here in console mode:

[image]

Here in normal mode:

[image]

How could I control it?

Remark: I had a different behavior using Vim 8.2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:terminal` output colors in Vim are set by `:h g:terminal_ansi_colors` variable (array of colors) and `:h hl-Terminal` color.

If it doesn't match your colorscheme then either a) the colorscheme has never set it (i.e. a broken/outdated one); or, b) it is a Vim bug; as far as I remember, there was one floating some time ago, but it is already fixed, so, if this is a case, you only have to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @Matt the global variable is set correctly and I'm running the version 9.0.1306 of the 13th of February. I understand that I should report a bug in Vim.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt There should be also `:h hl-Terminal` color set, so I've updated my answer. I guess your color scheme misses this one.

Comment: Great it works. Thanks!